# How would I include and configure a ruby library in a Chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I want to include the Diplomat gem in my Chef cookbook so that I can perform Consul variable lookups in .erb templates.

I need to configure the Consul URL:

```
irb(main):015:0> require 'diplomat'
irb(main):016:0> Diplomat.configure do |config|
irb(main):017:1*   config.url = "consulurl:80"
irb(main):018:1> end
```

Set a variable as the URL path:

```
irb(main):020:0> kv_path = "path/to/variable"
=> "path/to/variable"
```

And finally, perform the lookup within the templates.

```
irb(main):022:0> foo = Diplomat::Kv.get(kv_path + '/test_foo_123')
=> "bar"
```

Where in the cookbook would I need to write the configuration code above such that I can perform variable lookups within .erb templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `chef_gem` resource, but make sure to run it during the compile phase:

```
chef_gem 'diplomat' do
  action :nothing
  compile_time false
end.run_action(:install)
require 'diplomat'
```

Comment: This saved my chef recipe as the system gems were not loaded by _require_. I had download the gem for chef specifically using the above command. Then use the below line to make it load 
`chef_gem "down"`
`require 'down'`

Comment: @coderanger Thanks, but you say 'make sure to run it during the 'compile phase' but you have `compile_time false`. Is this a typo or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Installing gems with Chef is relatively painless. Most of the time, you can use the gem_package resource, which behaves very similarly to the native package resource:

`gem_package 'httparty'`

You can even specify the gem version to install:

`gem_package 'httparty' do
  version '0.12.0'
end`

You may have also seen the chef_gem resource. What's the difference?

> The chef_gem and gem_package resources are both used to install Ruby
>   gems. For any machine on which the chef-client is installed, there are
>   two instances of Ruby. One is the standard, system-wide instance of
>   Ruby and the other is a dedicated instance that is available only to
>   the chef-client. Use the chef_gem resource to install gems into the
>   instance of Ruby that is dedicated to the chef-client. Use the
>   gem_package resource to install all other gems (i.e. install gems
>   system-wide).

source: https://sethvargo.com/using-gems-with-chef/

Comment: As you might imagine from something in 2013, that post is wildly out of date. Please disregard most of it.